# How to control fields in a table using angular 6?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to show items from using a table by this structure :

```
   columns: any[] = [
   { field: 'title', header: 'Type de congé' },
   { field: 'nbDay', header: 'Nombre de jours' },
   { field: 'isExceptional', header: 'Congé exceptionnel' }
  ];
```

My question is "how to make a condition on the third field and replacing the value of the attribute 'isExceptional' by a string : for example : if isexceptional==true I get 'Yes' else I get 'NO' ?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the string value using Elvis operator `?` like this -

```
{{isexceptional ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
```

Comment: i want to change this :
   { field: 'isExceptional', header: 'Congé exceptionnel' }
by your answer! how to do it?

Comment: @SèmahSboui didn't getting your point, can you explain bit more

Answer (score 0):

here i solve that by using pipes i created a pipe that recieves the current value and transorm the resulat into an other :

```
  import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
   @Pipe ({
   name : 'yesno'
   })
   export class YesNoPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(val : Boolean) : String {
 if(val==true)  
 return 'Oui';
 else if(val==false)
 return 'Non';
      }
      }
```

then i used it on columns declaration